# Distance between numbers

Tags: matrices, statistics

I have a matrix of values (eg 0.07216 and 28.18433), But I requier all numbers to be an integer. Will multiplying the whole matrix by say 100 achive this without changing how statistically significant the distance between the two numbers are?

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by a statistically significant difference? Do you have some kind of metric for that?

Comment: The counts are measures of abundance of something in a sample and I will be seeing what somethings are significantly differentially higher compared to all the same something in all ofther samples

Comment: So are you just comparing the values inside the same matrix? Or do you have several matrices?

Comment: just within one matrix :)

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what kind of statistical test you're using, but I guess you're using some averages and standard deviations of the values, right? If you have a data set $X$ and another data set $Y=\alpha X$ (multiplied by $\alpha$), then of course the mean of the new set is
$$
\mu_Y = \alpha \mu_X
$$
and the (sample) standard deviation is
$$
s_Y = \alpha s_X
$$
if I'm not mistaken (?) ... So yeah, I guess the values of the statistical test won't change. You can just test it out, too ...